# WebStorm closing brackets

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using JetBrains PhpStorm as my IDE and I have a French Keyboard (AZERTY), my problem is I can't insert a closing curly bracket `}` !

I can do so in Sublime or any other editor by typing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> .

Does any one have this problem ?

Comment: Do french Keyboards not have curly brackets?!!

Comment: AFAIK the closing `}` is inserted automatically in a code when you typing opening `{` ( I believe this can be disabled, but it is enabled by default).

Comment: In any case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155170 (check the comment) .. which is marked as duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75636 . Also -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134554 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=azerty%20french in general)

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne your solution works I had just to remove the shortcut !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` screen has a special button -- "find action by shortcut" -- when you use it, it will list all actions that have that specific shortcut associated with.

If you use <kbd>Alt Gr + =</kbd> there (which you use to type `}` character using your keyboard layout)  .. you will notice that IDE recognizes such shortcut as <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + =</kbd>. Basically, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl + Shift</kbd> (may actually vary depending on OS).

You will also notice that such shortcut already has association with some action. If you remove such association .. or assign another shortcut to that action, then your <kbd>Alt Gr + =</kbd> will start working.

Related tickets from the Issue Tracker:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155170 (marked as duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75636 -- I suggest watching it and any related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notifications on any progress)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134554

Comment: ... and dont hold your breath waiting for a fix.  _Created by Sébastien Douche 20 Nov 2010 17:20_

Comment: if you can't find which action uses the shortcut, just add the same shortcut to any action and it will tell you which one is gonna be overwritten